# How to resolve IPv4 first on Alpine Linux?

Tags: networking, ipv6, alpine-linux, ipv4

It seems that when resolving hosts on Alpine Linux, the default behavior is to try IPv6 first and falling back to IPv4.

But sometimes it takes a lot of time to resolve, and there are connections when IPv6 is blocked entirely making it frustating.

Is there a way to configure the resolver to try IPv4 first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found that I can *disable IPv6 entirely* and that makes the trick for me.

Adding to `/etc/sysctl.d/local.conf` ([source](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Sysctl.conf)):

```
# Force IPv6 off
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And reloading the configuration:

```
# sysctl --system
```

Answer (score 3):

What is happening with [Alpine Linux](https://www.alpinelinux.org/) is that Alpine does not use [`glibc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), rather it uses [`musl libc`](https://musl.libc.org/).

---

With [`glibc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) you could prefer IPv4 over IPv6 simply by adding this line to `/etc/gai.conf`:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

---

However, this *does not work with Alpine*, since the [`musl libc`](https://musl.libc.org/) implementation of `getaddrinfo(3)` does not support this.

You can see the thread about this request [here](https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2020/07/30/6).

You can also see the wiki on [Running glibc programs](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs) in Alpine.